# C - multidimensional array allocation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm using the following C function to emulate a 4D array. Other than adding additional loops, is there a good way to make this function generic enough to create n-dimensional arrays?

```
double ****alloc_4D_data(int wlen, int xlen, int ylen, int zlen)
{
    int i,j,k;

    double ****ary = (jdouble****)malloc(wlen*sizeof(jdouble***));

    for (i = 0; i < wlen; i++) 
    {
        ary[i] = (jdouble***)malloc(xlen*sizeof(jdouble**));

        for (j = 0; j < xlen; j++) 
        {
            ary[i][j] = (jdouble**)malloc(ylen*sizeof(jdouble*));

            for (k = 0; k < ylen; k++) 
            {
                ary[i][j][k] = (jdouble*)malloc(zlen*sizeof(jdouble));
            }
        }
    }

    return ary;
}
```

Comment: Why not malloc it at a single go?

Comment: It isn't trivial to add the extra dimensions other than by adding more loops.  You will need to consider the memory release process too; also, the clean up if any of the allocations above fails.

Comment: You can drop the casts

Comment: This *specific* function? No. *A* function (coupled with a multi-dim array function fmaily and a traits struct to hold the dimension info)? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language, every elements of the multi dimensional array are stored in a continual memory area. So you just need to calculate the total number of elements of all N dimensional and malloc the whole memory. Such as:

```
/* int *Nlen is a N length array to store every dimensional array length
 * int N is the Nlen array length indicates how many dimensions.
 */
double *alloc_ND_data(int wlen, int *Nlen, int N)
{
    int i;
    int total = 1;
    double *array;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
    /* Every dimension should mul the next depth dimension size */ 
        total *= Nlen[i]; 
    }
    array = malloc(wlen*total*sizeof(jdouble));

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Of course now you also need a function to access an array element, because calculating the offset for some array position also needs a loop.

Comment: @hyde, Yes, you must make at least one loop to find the element. But there is only one loop needed to handle even the N-dimentional array. So it is a common way to create or access element from the N-dimensional array. BTW, I find some errors in my example code, corrected already.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays you build in this way have very obvious recursive structure. I.e. i-th level memory is just an array of pointers to (i-1)-th level memory. Only the 0-th level memory contains the actual objects instead of pointers. So, you can easily implement it in that way, passing in the sizes in a separate integer array.

The recursion in this case is going to be tail recursion, meaning that it can be rather easily replaced with a genuinely cyclic implementation (with no need for intermediate LIFO storage). But to me it looks like one of those cases where recursion will work fine and will look more readable.